# Is Brownian bridge adapted to a filtration

Tags: brownian-motion, wiener-measure

For t∈[0,1], we define X(t)=B(t)−tB(1), where {B(t):t≥0} is a standard Brownian motion.
My question is, is X(t) adapted to the filtration generated by the standard brownian motion B(t) over the interval [0,1]?
I'm not clear about the filtration adapted processes. Could anyone please help me here?

Comment: Of course not, right? We don't know what $B_1$ is  at time $t<1$, so how can the process be adapted?

Comment: Can you please elaborate the answer?

Comment: If the process $X_t$ is adapted, then $X_t$ should be measurable with respect to the sigma-algebra generated by all $B_{s}$  with $s<t$. But then, for example $X_{0.5} = B_1 - B_{0.5}$ is not measurable with respect to the sigma-algebra generated by $B_{s}, s \leq 0.5$, because $B_1$ is not measurable with respect to that sigma-algebra.

Comment: Sorry to ask you again. Then is X(t) adapted by B(t) over  [0,T]?

Comment: No, because $X_t$ depends on $B_1$ which is not $B_t$ adapted over $[0,t]$ for $t<1$.

Comment: Thank you for your time.

Comment: Great, you are welcome